# After sharing a post using social-share-button the page got closed abruptly in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, socialshare

I am using "social-share-button' gem in my rails application (rails 4.0.1), after sharing my Post over social networking sites, the page is getting closed abruptly.

Any way to customize the redirection path and indicate the same to a valid page with a nice confirmation Message ?

my View section :

```
<%= social_share_button_tag(@blog.name, :url =>"http://192.168.10.11:3009/blogs/") %>
```

Social_share_button.rb configuration File :

```
SocialShareButton.configure do |config|
config.allow_sites = %w(twitter facebook google_plus)
end
```

Any ways to fix this issue ?

Comment: Such feature should be unobtrusive, why not you just use available addons that work well, like AddThis?

Comment: I tried "AddThis" works like a charm, but while redirecting it shows the middle mans name in URL path (like addthis.com/) that's why I prefer using gem over this addson.